# Run script from i3 config

Tags: shortcut-keys, i3-wm

I'm using i3-wm and I have Mod3 working as a hotkey. I have the following in './config/i3/config':

```
#This command works
  bindsym Mod3+f exec "firefox" 

#This doesn't work nor do my other scripts
  bindsym Mod3+w exec "openBrowser"
```

Both of these commands work fine when I run them from bash but only the 'firefox' command runs with the hotkey.

openBrowser is a script in /opt/bin/ which is in my path. Also tried doing `exec "/opt/bin/openBrowser"`

Note: I also noticed when I'm in bash if I do Mod3+w my cursor blinks, where as if I do Mod3+[any unset key] the key writes it's value to the screen. So it seems the system is at least trying to run the function.

Comment: Where (in which file) do do add `/opt/bin` to your `PATH`?

Comment: @adaephon ~/.bashrc I've also tried using the full path in the i3 config so I know the issue isn't related to path.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently [i3 uses `sh`](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_i3bar_command) to launch stuff, and does not source `$PATH` from `~/.bashrc` :

```
cat ~/.xsession-errors
(...)
/bin/sh: 1: mycommand: not found
```

So, just create a `~/.xsessionrc` file and put something like this in it :

```
if [ -d "/opt/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="/opt/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Then logout and back in ; It should work now.